# Fortran : automatically re-assign pointers to new target when it is copied

Tags: fortran

Here is an illustration of the problem I have been having in the last days. Suppose you have the following structures:

```
TYPE superImportant
    INTEGER(C_INT) :: one
END TYPE superImportant

TYPE lessImportant
    TYPE(superImportant), POINTER :: ptr 
END TYPE lessImportant

TYPE(superImportant), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: superStruct
TYPE(lessImportant),  DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         :: lesserStruct
```

At some point in the code, `superStruct` and `lesserStruct` are allocated to sizes `superSize` and `lesserSize`, and for each element of `lesserStruct`, something like this is done:

```
lesserStruct(lesserNumber)%ptr => superStruct(superNumber)
```

Then, a bit further in the code, I need to re-allocate both `superStruct` and `lesserStruct` to larger sizes. So I do the following:

```
TYPE(superImportant), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: tempSuperStruct
TYPE(lessImportant),  DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         :: tempLesserStruct

ALLOCATE(tempLesserStruct(lesserSize + newLesserSize))
tempLesserStruct(1:lesserSize) = lesserStruct(1:lesserSize)
CALL MOVE_ALLOC(tempLesserStruct, lesserStruct)
```

which works like a charm : all pointers are correctly copied and I can access `lesserStruct(.)%ptr` for all elements in `1:lesserSize`.
However, if I try to do the same with the other structure :

```
ALLOCATE(tempSuperStruct(superSize + newSuperSize))
tempSuperStruct(1:superSize) = superStruct(1:superSize)
CALL MOVE_ALLOC(tempSuperStruct, superStruct)
```

Then I can no longer access `lesserStruct(.)%ptr`. I identified that this is because of the line with the `=`. Note that if I do instead:

```
CALL MOVE_ALLOC(superStruct,tempSuperStruct)
```

I can still access `lesserStruct(.)%ptr`, because, as said in the standard : `If to has the TARGET attribute, any pointer associated with from at the time of the call to MOVE_ALLOC becomes correspondingly associated with to.` Unfortunately, I still have to do an `=` step after that, during which I lose my pointer association.

So here is my question : is there a way to copy my structure in a "MOVE_ALLOC fashion" so the pointers associated with it will follow automatically ? More generally, is there a better solution to extend the size of my structures ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of MOVE_ALLOC.

When you reallocate the lesserStruct using a temporary allocatable and MOVE_ALLOC, in fact, you are preserving the pointers and this is why you can still use them after this step.

When, in the second step, you are reallocating the superStruct using the temporary allocatable and the MOVE_ALLOC, you are CHANGING the memory location where superStruct stores its values.

When, in step 2, instead you simple do a

```
CALL MOVE_ALLOC(superStruct,tempSuperStruct)
```

What you are doing is passing the allocation from "superStruct" to "tempSuperStruct". Now, superStruct is deallocated and tempSuperStruct now holds the allocated space. But if you look to it, you will see that it has only 'superSize' elements, and not 'superSize + newSuperSize'. The lesseStruct still works (At least to the superSize element), because the memory space to where is points is still being used in the same way.

And so, the reason why you misunderstand the standard, is that any pointer associated with the FROM will be associated with the TO if it has the TARGET attribute. In your case, any pointer associated with the "tempSuperStructure" that is your FROM will be associated with the superStructure after the MOVE_ALLOC, not the pointers from lesserStruct...

See?

In your case, the only way I see is to re-assign the pointers to the elements of superStruct after the reallocation of lesserStruct.

Answer (score 1):

No - you will need to rethink your approach.

If the pointer is always associated with elements in a particular array, which seems to be the case here, then you can just store the index of the element of interest.  Fortran has very good support for arrays and array indexing operations, so you might as well take advantage of this support.

An alternative is to hold the individual elements of the target array as persistent scalar objects, that are effectively not moved, rather than assigned, when you expand the target array.

```
TYPE superImportant
  INTEGER(C_INT) :: one
END TYPE superImportant

TYPE superImportantWrapper
  ! Using a pointer to reference the object, because 
  ! it ensures the target is a TARGET, and simplifies 
  ! assignment.  ALLOCATABLE is also a possibility, 
  ! with other changes.
  TYPE(superImportant), POINTER :: item => NULL()
CONTAINS
  ! Elided code to deallocate the item component.
  FINAL :: wrapper_Final
END TYPE supertImportantWrapper

TYPE lessImportant
  TYPE(superImportant), POINTER :: ptr 
END TYPE lessImportant

! The super array is of the wrapper type.
TYPE(superImportantWrapper), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, TARGET   &
    :: superStruct
TYPE(lessImportant),  DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: lesserStruct

! Elided code to populate each scalar component of the wrapper type.
DO i = 1, xxx ; ALLOCATE(superStruct(i)%item) ; ... ; END DO

! Point at the component, not the wrapper object.
lesserStruct(lesserNumber)%ptr => superStruct(superNumber)%item

...

! Time to grow?  Again, array operations on the wrapper.
TYPE(superImportantWrapper), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: tempSuperStruct

ALLOCATE(tempSuperStruct(superSize + newSuperSize))
! Intrinsic assignment of the pointer component means it maintains 
! the reference to the same object that lesser struct is referencing.
tempSuperStruct(1:superSize) = superStruct(1:superSize)
CALL MOVE_ALLOC(tempSuperStruct, superStruct)
```